# OnClick getting undefined method `model_name' for NilClass: Class

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am new to rails. I am trying to create a form with name, email, phone number, and message fields. When I click on the button which is linked to the form I am getting an error:

> undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Here's the code for _form.html.erb page:

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contact from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
 <% end %>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Name" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Email"%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Phone Number"%>
   </div>
</div> 
</div>
<div class = "col-md-8">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description,  :class=>"form-control", :size=>"20x5", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Message"%>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", :class=> "button1"%>
 </div>  
<% end %>
```

This is the code for contacts_controller.rb is:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController


  # GET /contacts/new
  # GET /contacts/new.xml

  def new
  @contact = Contact.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @contact }
  end
end

# POST /contacts
# POST /contacts.xml
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.save
      format.html { redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @contact, :status => :created, :location => @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @contact.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, I have added `resources :contacts` in the `routes.rb` file

Please help me understand what is the issue here.
Thanks.

Comment: Can u copy and put the error stack here.

Comment: I hope you have defined an Model contact.rb too, just confirming?

Comment: yes i have defined a model contact.rb as well

Comment: [here's](http://pastebin.com/vzBx5rke) the full error. @HarryBomrah

Comment: here's the model

`class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :name,:email
end
`

Answer (score 0):

Please modify `routes.rb` to:

Use

```
resources :contacts
```

Instead of

```
resources: contacts
```

Comment: Thanks, I have it that way only on the code. Just a typing error from my side.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `@contact` in a partial - it should be a local var, defined when you invoke the partial:

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: { contact: @contact } %>
```

... then...

```
#_form.html.erb
<%= form_for contact do ...
```

---

The `model_name` error is from `form_for` - when it takes an object, it will look for the `model_name` attribute, as to populate the path etc.

Because you're receiving the error in conjunction with `NilClass:Class`, it suggests your `@contact` variable isn't defined.

The above is my recommendation; you shouldn't be calling `@instance_variables` in your partials.